# oracle like with param

Tags: oracle, jpa

I need to search with params in Oracle used `like` with percent clause '%',

for example:

```
WHERE (YPOLOIPO > 0) /*search*/ AND ((GROUPNAME LIKE '%PRE%' AND MEMBERNAME LIKE '%LIO%'))
```

but I need to use parameters like folow:

```
WHERE (YPOLOIPO > 0) /*search*/ AND ((GROUPNAME LIKE '%'?'%' AND MEMBERNAME LIKE '%'?'%'))
```

but the previous exmple is not working, also if I put the question mark `?` in quotes `'%?%'`this is not regognized.

How it is possimple to use params in double percent?

Comment: Are you using prepared statements directly in Oracle, or from an application language using Oracle?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen From an application language (java jpa) using Oracle

Answer (score 2):

You can concatenate the bind placeholder:

```
WHERE (YPOLOIPO > 0) /*search*/ AND ((GROUPNAME LIKE '%'||?||'%' AND MEMBERNAME LIKE '%'||?||'%'))
```

Comment: This clause return ORA-00911: invalid character

Comment: In a Java parsed statement? Odd; the same code worked with your fixed values? (Your statement doesn't have a semicolon on he end, does it?)

Comment: This error comes from oracle not from java, and the same code worked fine with the fixed values

Comment: Yes, I meant the Oracle statement this is a fragment of. The Java string you prepare should not have a semicolon within it - i.e. `"select * from dual"` and not `"select * from dual;"`. Having that stay semicolon is a common cause of that error, but it's unlikely you've added one to the working fixed value version.

Comment: @Giorgos - are you sure you're using the right bind placeholder? I don't use it but [this doc](https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/parameter) shows slightly different syntax to plain JDBC calls?

Answer (score 1):

The way you typically bind a string literal surrounded on one or both sides by a wildcard `%` using Java prepared statements is to do the concatenation from Java, e.g.

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE MEMBERNAME LIKE ?";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
String name = "LIO";
ps.setString(1, "%" + name + "%");
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

while (rs.next()) {
    // process result set
}
```

Comment: It is not possilble the surrounded parameter with wildcard `%` comes from query?

Comment: Did you mean to have `WHERE MEMBERNAME LIKE ?` rather than `WHERE MEMBERNAME = ?`? You could also use `String sql = "SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE MEMBERNAME LIKE '%' || ? || '%'"` and just pass in the name without the wildcards.

Comment: It is not possilbe oracle returns  ORA-00911: invalid character